# How can I view a sum of numbers from cells?

Tags: jquery

How, using jquery, can I display a sum of numbers from cells with the same classes? I need to display the sum like under:

```
In 2014: 105 l. //sum of every number from cell that have class "2014"
In 2013: 140 l. //sum of every number from cell that have class "2013"
In 2012: 50 l. //sum of every number from cell that have class "2012"


<td class="2014">60 l.</td>
<td class="2014">45 l.</td>
<td class="2013">60 l.</td>
<td class="2013">80 l.</td>
<td class="2012">20 l.</td>
<td class="2012">30 l.</td>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the jQuery you tried.

Comment: I have no idea how should I start with this script. I hope, that someone can me show a tip, which brings me on the right way to solve this task.

Comment: Here you go: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try writing a function like this:

```
function calculateSum(className) {
    var sum = 0;

    $('.' + className).each(function() {
        var tdText = $(this).text();
        var tdNumber = parseInt(tdText.split(' ')[0]);

        if(!isNaN(tdNumber)) {
            sum += tdNumber;
        }
    });

    return sum;
}
```

This function just shows you how to calculate the sum... but not sure how the rest of your HTML will be structured so you will probably need to add extra logic to handle different rows and such...